# App inside virtual machine can't connect

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have in virtual box a guest windows system running in an Ubuntu host. And i want to run a homebroker on it which just won't connect to the stock broker so i can login. The internet connection in the VM works perfectly, i already did allow the app through the firewall and installed all versions of net framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a problem with the network connection from my university i was using which wouldn't allow the app.